# Set up JSONField in HTML page

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've created this model

```
class RoadConstruction(models.Model):
    fromCity = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    toCity = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    jsonData = models.JSONField(null=True) 
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

So when I use Forms and add the form into my html page it generates a text area for jsonData. But here is the catch I know how to like properly define the contents of JSONField but the thing is the JSON is going to be dynamic and it all depends upon the user who is submitting the form. So, I cannot fix the JSONField.

I'll explain with examples of what I'm expecting with JSONField.

`fromCity`, `toCity`, `status` is self explanatory as it can be very easily implemented with Forms.

In `xyz.html` page there will be initially one row of empty form.

| colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| valueA | valueB | valueC |

Here suppose the user gave above inputs i.e `valueA`, `valueB`, `valueC`. So I want data to be stored in JSONField as

```
[
    {
        'colA': valueA,
        'colB': valueB,
        'colC': valueC,
    }
]
```

Also there will be a ADD button which will add a new row like this and then the user can fill it.
| colA | colB | colC |
|------|------|------|
| valueA1 | valueB1 | valueC1 |
| valueA2 | valueB2 | valueC2 |

Then the JSONField should look like this:

```
[
    {
        'colA': valueA1,
        'colB': valueB1,
        'colC': valueC1,
    },
    {
        'colA': valueA2,
        'colB': valueB2,
        'colC': valueC2,
    }
]
```

So the user can add rows as per requirements.

So, how should I implement this type of thing? If directly using the ModelForms then it is showing textarea and I can't expect my website users to know JSON.
How should I make it dynamic to take as many as values required and store it into the jsondata and then I can easily save it on the DB?

**XYZ.HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It shows textarea corresponding to jsonData.

Comment: You can do it in the backend - with Django outside users' sight.

Comment: @bichanna yes! but how to do that? How to compile all the data in the form present in xyz.html page into JSON and then assign into JSONField?

Comment: Could you show us an example of your `xyz.html`

Comment: @bichanna I added xyz.html

Comment: How do you want your users to type in the textfield-like-field (jsonfield)?

Comment: @bichanna there will be tables shaped as form. User can fill the row and then click on ADD button and then another row will appear and user can fill it again. So, when user finally submits the form the data entered into tables gets converted into JSON and then this JSON data is uploaded to DB. I don't know how to assign the generated JSON to jsonData of models.

Answer (score 0):

Always search [django packages](https://djangopackages.org/packages/) and more generally, Google "Django + keywords relevant to task at hand"

[Django-JSON-widget](https://github.com/jmrivas86/django-json-widget) looks relevant, but I have only just found it and can't offer any further comment.

It also occurs to me that the restricted form of JSON which you describe maps directly onto a Django Formset, templated as three columns. Once `formset.is_valid()` you just have to pick out the cleaned data from each form in the set  and assemble it into a list-of-dicts which you can then store in a JSONField.